# np.any() multiple logic statements

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a numpy array with multiple values (for example: `v = np.array([0.81597636, 0.93198024])`.
I want to check if any of the values in `v`is in a range between `xmin`and `xmax`. I tried the following:

```py
if np.any(xmin <= v <= xmax):
   print("Is in range")
```

But i get the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I do not get the error when I do:

```py
if np.any(xmin <= v) and np.any(v <= xmax):
   print("Is in range")
```

But this wouldn't work since there could be an element in `v`, which is larger than `xmin` and there could also be an element, which is smaller than `xmax` but its not necessarily the same element.

I think the problem is, that I am using multiple logic statements within `np.any()`, but I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check both conditions separately and combine them with a `bitwise AND`:

```
v = np.array([0.81597636, 0.93198024])
(v > 0.85) & (v < 1.)
# array([False,  True])
```

Note that as a result from the first comparison you get:

```
0.85 < v
# array([False,  True])
```

So note that doing the following will raise an error:

```
0.85 < v < 1.
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

The reason behind this is that you're comparing a `1x2` array with an `int`, which results in another `1x2` array, and of course, the result is ambiguous. You need to compare a boolean array with another, which is why you must chain the conditions as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way by using List Comprehension

```
v = np.array([0.81597636, 0.93198024])
xmin, xmax = 0.8, 0.9
check_list = [True if xmin <= i <= xmax else False for i in v]
```

Result:

```
[True, False]
```

Comment: Is it sensible to use a list comprehension when you have a Numpy array?